# Insinkerator instant hot water tank connected to sink faucet

Tags: plumbing, sink

I have an Insinkerator instant hot system with its own tap in my kitchen. I was thinking about taking a tee off the outlet and plumbing it into the hot water side of my faucet. That way, I would get near instant hot water on the sink faucet as well.

Instant hot tank > tee > instant hot water at faucet.

I'm sure the restrictions of the flow through the instant hot system would result in lower water pressure so maybe I could connect it to the hot faucet with some sort of tee and balancer to get both pressure and at least some of the instant hot? Has anyone accomplished this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this will work on the ones I have installed the chamber is vented so if there were pressure on the output side they will leak as they heat up if not any time the faucet is turned on. Yours may be different but I would look at its internal plumbing a little closer prior to trying this. I should note the water valve is on the input side of the heated tank any excess expansion comes out the tap or to the drain via an overflow line.

Answer (score 0):

The instant hot tank can not be used as an inlet to the faucet.

I deconstructed the instant hot tank to find out how it works. The whole tank, as far as I can find, is low pressure so it's only pushing out hot water as new cold water flows in. This means that if I took a tee off the outlet, it would only receive hot water while the instant hot button is held down on the tap.

[image: Instant Hot Diagram]

Comment: Brian this is what I said   You added a picture but as I said it is vented.